# How to handle an exectution time error in AS3 (Error #1502)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'd like to know whether there is a way to add an error handler for a #1502 execution time error in AS3.

A couple of notes:

- I am aware that the max script execution time can be set on the publish options. It takes values as high as 16 bit (0-65535). So there is a max of 18 hours. The script does not get terminated after 60 seconds in the context I use it.
- I use it in an application built with mProjector. There is an event listener on a button that opens a file browser dialogue. As long as the browser is open the event handler does not continue. If the maximum script execution time is exceeded I get the #1502.
- If there is no way I'll just set that limit very high. Nevertheless building something that will break if you leave a dialogue open for like a day is not neat. It's never gonna happen but still I wondered if there is a proper way to avoid things like this.

Thanks.

**Additional info:**

Shortened code:

```
bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browse);
function browse(e:Event) {
    var selectedFilesString:String = mSystem.chooseFiles(chooseFileTitle, initFileName, initFolderName, fileFilter, defaultFileType);
    ...
}
```

So this involves the mSystem.chooseFiles() method detailed here:

http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs/AS3-mSys-chooseFiles.htm

But like I said I'm interested in wether there is an error handler for this error. Not in what might cause it and what does not or wether mProjector is well implemented or not etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can catch [ScriptTimeoutError](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/errors/ScriptTimeoutError.html), but only once.  See [this blog post](http://joshblog.net/2006/03/01/you-can-catch-timeouts-and-stack-overflows-in-actionscript-3/).

Comment: I tried to avoid this kind of answer by the notes above. I really am in a situation where the timeout occurs. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Judging from their API (which indeed does not use event handling to prevent this kind of error), it seems to me that you should contact the developers of the mProjector component - this is clearly a design flaw.  Anyway, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's interesting. Too bad you get but one shot at catching this.

Comment: Like I said: It shouldn't even be necessary to catch this.  If the program is well-written, there should never be a script that stalls the player.  So as a last resort, I suppose one shot is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with wrapping my app into an .EXE using Zinc, where basically the script timed out while waiting for the user to trigger an event that would be fired back to action script. In fact, it was a confirm dialog box, likely the exact same situation you are encountering just with a different external interface / wrapper.

With the Latest version of Zinc they have promised to address this type of issue but in your case I would look and see if mProjector has any asynchronous dialog box call that will not halt the action script, or maybe even a setting to close the dialog box after a few seconds.

If not then you either set the timeout to something ridiculous, which feels very messy I agree;however, you are wrapping it in an EXE that can make it feel at least a little less messy, or you use your own dialog boxes and stay away from any mProject calls that completely halt your action script.

I briefly looked here but nothing seemed to pop out, perhaps you are more familiar:
http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs

Good luck, if you get a better solution figured out let me know as I am curious how mProject will handle it vs Zinc.

Comment: I see there is an mApplication.abortFunction(), says it is for asynchornous calls but I'd say it's worth a try, documentation here: [http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs/AS3-mApp-abortFunction.htm](http://www.screentime.com/software/flash-projector/docs/AS3-mApp-abortFunction.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting a Timer before calling `FileReference.browse()`, and if the timer completes without the browse operation completes calling `FileReference.cancel()`.